# How to make add a customer attribute in Magento Programmatically

Tags: customer-attribute, programmatically, upgrade-script

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer','badge', array( 
    'label'             => 'Badge',
    'type'              => 'text',    //backend_type
    'input'             => 'multiselect', //frontend_input
    'backend'           => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',    
    'global'            =>  Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'source'            => 'marketplace/eav_entity_attribute_source_badge', // Goes to Step 2
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'default'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'unique'            => false,
    'note'              => ''
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'badge')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array(
        'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'customer_address_edit',
        'checkout_onepage_register', 'checkout_onepage_register_guest', 'checkout_onepage_billing_address',
        'adminhtml_customer','checkout_onepage_shipping_address','checkout_multishipping_register'
    ))
    ->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

My Badge,php

```
class Company_Marketplace_Model_System_Config_Source_Badge
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{

    protected $_options;

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/badge')->getCollection();
        $allattributes = array();
        foreach ($collection as $data) {
            $allattributes[] = array(
                'value' => $data->getBadgeName(),
                'label' => $data->getBadgeName()
            );
        }

        return $allattributes;
    }
}
```

Get error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::addAttribute()
in app\code\local\Company\Marketplace\sql\marketplace_setup\mysql4-upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php on line 6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you have this piece of xml in the `config.xml` file inside the `<global>` tag

```
    <resources>
        <[module]_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Company_Marketplace</module>
            </setup>
        </[module]_setup>
    </resources>
```

You need to tell magento to use the customer setup model for your setup.  You can do that by transforming the markup above into:

```
    <resources>
        <[module]_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Company_Marketplace</module>
                <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class> <!-- this needs to be added -->
            </setup>
        </[module]_setup>
    </resources>
```

**[EDIT]**
add this method to your source model also:

```
public function getOptionText($value)
{
    $isMultiple = false;
    if (strpos($value, ',')) {
        $isMultiple = true;
        $value = explode(',', $value);
    }

    $options = $this->getAllOptions(false);

    if ($isMultiple) {
        $values = array();
        foreach ($options as $item) {
            if (in_array($item['value'], $value)) {
                $values[] = $item['label'];
            }
        }
        return $values;
    }

    foreach ($options as $item) {
        if ($item['value'] == $value) {
            return $item['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Error solved when i m click on Manage customer it will return this error Fatal error: Class Company_Marketplace_Model_System_Config_Source_Badge contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Interface::getAllOptions) in F:\wamp\www\magento1\app\code\local\Company\Marketplace\Model\Eav\Entity\Attribute\Source\Badge.php on line 3

Comment: You need to implement the method `getOptionText` as well in your custom source model.

Comment: Please can you show that how to implement that method

Comment: @ND17 I edited my answer.